# url building in C#

Tags: c#, url

I need to build a URL with a query string in C#.  What is the best approach to doing this?  Right now, I'm using something like,

```
string url = String.Format("foo.aspx?{0}={1}&{2}={3}", "a", 123, "b", 456);
```

Is there a better, preferred approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is a good method if it's always know what parameters you have, if this is unknown at the time you could always keep a List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> with the key being the name and value being the value, then build the query string using a foreach loop like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> q in theList)
{
 // build the query string here.
    sb.Append(string.format("{0}={1}&", q.Key, q.Value);
}
```

note: the code is not tested and has not been compiled, so it may not work exactly as is.

Comment: That's the way I like. Also you could wrap it in function that takes Dictionary<string, string> or better <string,object>.

Comment: Key and Value need to be URL-parameter-encoded before being concatenated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should be using Server.UrlEncode on each of the arguments so that you don't send any bad characters in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a neat little open source library for exactly these kinds of things.  Check out [WebBuddy](http://webbuddy.codeplex.com/), and in particular [UriBuddy](http://webbuddy.codeplex.com/#UriBuddy).  The binaries are for Silverlight, but you can easily [browse the source](http://webbuddy.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx) and rip whatever you need.

Here is how you'd call UriBuddy:

```
// Take a base url
Uri sample = new Uri("http://www.nytimes.com");

// some highly useful parameters
Dictionary<String, String> query = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"param1","nice"},
    {"param2","code man"}

};


// create a new url using a chained style of coding
Uri newSample = sample
    .AppendPath("/pages/world")
    .AppendQueryValues(query);
```

BTW, I've never had to do this kind of stuff outside of Silverlight.  I'm fairly sure the "real" .NET library has built-in functions that look very similar to mine.